# Does Wo send Simon Kress deliberately into death?

Tags: sandkings

Near the final scene of [*Sandkings*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandkings_(novelette)) (1979) by George R. R. Martin, Wo tells Kress to leave the house immediately and run away in a particular direction, promising to pick him up.

However Wo never picks him up, even well after agreed time. Instead, running in a given direction, Kress ultimately approaches the fortress of the Orange Sandking who ran away from the same house before and have suffered the most from Kress' abusive behavior in the past.

Did Wo (and Shade) deliberately send Kress to the Orange Sandking?

Comment: I took the liberty of radically editing your question to remove the speculative, opinion-based elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He may not have intended for Kress to die.  But, it is hard to believe that he didn't know that Kress would screw up and let them out.  Maybe Shade wanted a friend. ;)

Answer (score 2):

From this:

> “Do not be absurd,” Wo said. “A first-stage
>   sandking is more like a sperm than like an infant. The wars temper and
>   control them in nature. Only one in a hundred reaches the second
>   stage. Only one in a thousand achieves the third and final plateau and
>   becomes like Shade. **Adult sandkings are not sentimental about the
>   small maws. There are too many of them, and their mobiles are pests.”**
>   She sighed. “And all this talk wastes time. That white sandking is
>   going to waken to full sentience soon. It is not going to need you any
>   longer, and it hates you, and it will be very hungry. The
>   transformation is taxing. The maw must eat enormous amounts both
>   before and after. So you have to get out of there. Do you
>   understand?”
>      “I can’t, ” Kress said. “My
>   skimmer is destroyed, and I can’t get any of the others to start. I
>   don’t know how to reprogram them. Can you come out for me?”
>       “Yes,” said Wo. “Shade and I will leave at
>   once, but it is more than two hundred kilometers from Asgard to you,
>   and there is equipment that we will need to deal with the deranged
>   sandking you’ve created. You cannot wait there. You have two feet.
>   Walk. Go due east, as near as you can determine, as quickly as you
>   can. The land out there is pretty desolate. We can find you easily
>   with an aerial search, and you’ll be safely away from the sandkings.
>   Do you understand?”

...and this:

> **At least he hoped it was east. He was not that
>   good at directions,** and he wasn’t certain which way he had run in his
>   initial panic, but since then he had made an effort to bear due east,
>   as Wo had suggested.
>      When he had been
>   running for several hours, with no sign of rescue, **Kress began to grow
>   certain that he had miscalculated his direction.**

...and the fact that Wo makes no mention of the orange Sandking, it seems more likely that Wo believes, along with Kress, that the orange Sandking is dead. Wo is most likely trying to help Kress and wants only to destroy the Sandkings that Kress drove insane. Kress simply started out in the wrong direction in his initial panic and ran into the orange Sandkings purely by accident before Wo could find him.